# how to divide the obtained sum of data

Tags: sql, count

I need to get the sum of the records matching the key and the result of it is my TOTALQUANTITY
then i need to split it for packages, max package size is 5.
so when i get a result(TOTALQUANTITY) equals to 13 i should get something like this:

```
    package  |ofpackages |totalquantity |quantityofpackage
    1        |3          |13            |5
    2        |3          |13            |5
    3        |3          |13            |3
```

my attempt:

```sql
SELECT 
  count(*) as TOTALQUANTITY,
  get_token(data1) data1,
  get_token(data2) data2,
  get_token(data3) data3,
  floor((row_number() over (partition BY get_token(data2) order by get_token(data2) ) - 1 ) / 5) package
FROM 
  --my working code
WHERE
  --my working conditions
GROUP BY 
  get_token(data1), 
  get_token(data2), 
  get_token(data3)
ORDER BY
  get_token(data2)
```

Totalquantity gives the correct value, but the package unfortunately doesn't :(
How it should be? how can i get the remaining values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the use `MOD()` to determine the remainder, if zero output the division, otherwise add the package amount to the totalquantity then divide and round.

Using a derived table makes this a little easier I believe:

```
SELECT
  TOTALQUANTITY,
  get_token(data1) data1,
  get_token(data2) data2,
  get_token(data3) data3,
  package,
  case when MOD(TOTALQUANTITY,package) = 0 
          then TOTALQUANTITY + package
          else round((TOTALQUANTITY + package)/package,0)
  end as quantityofpackage
FROM (
    SELECT 
      count(*) as TOTALQUANTITY,
      get_token(data1) data1,
      get_token(data2) data2,
      get_token(data3) data3,
      floor((row_number() over (partition BY get_token(data2) order by get_token(data2) ) - 1 ) / 5) package
    FROM 
      --my working code
    WHERE
      --my working conditions
    GROUP BY 
      get_token(data1), 
      get_token(data2), 
      get_token(data3)
    ) derived
ORDER BY
  data2
```

Note you don't specify which dbms you are using so I have assumed it supports `MOD()` if not it will have an equivalent e.g. [% in MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: i got "invalid number of arguments" for this row :/
case when MOD(TOTALQUANTITY / package) = 0

Comment: sorry `MOD(TOTALQUANTITY,package)`  mod takes 2 parameters

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from the example code how that's supposed to work.  Suppose there's a table which contains packages and quantities.

```
drop table if exists #package_quantities;
go
create table #package_quantities(
    package     int not null,
    quantity    int not null);
go
    
insert #package_quantities(package, quantity) values
(10, 10),
(10, 1),
(10, 2),
(20, 5),
(20, 9),
(30, 12),
(40, 20);
```

To generate new rows the query uses a [tally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) tvf called fnNumbers.  The CTE pack_cte sums quantitites for each package.  The query then splits the packages into bundles with a maximum quantity of 5.  Each subpackage has a unique sequence number 1, 2, 3...

fnNumbers tvf

```
create function [dbo].[fnNumbers](
  @zero_or_one   bit, 
  @n             bigint)
returns table with schemabinding as return
with n(n) as (select null from (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) n(n))
select 0 n where @zero_or_one = 0
union all
select top(@n) row_number() over(order by (select null)) n
from n na, n nb, n nc, n nd, n ne, n nf, n ng, n nh,
     n ni, n nj, n nk, n nl, n nm, n np, n nq, n nr;
```

Query

```
with pack_cte(package, sum_quantity) as (
    select package, sum(quantity)
    from #package_quantities
    group by package)
select p.package, p.sum_quantity, p_calc.num_packages, fn.n subpackage,
       case when p_calc.num_packages<>fn.n or (p_calc.num_packages=fn.n and p.sum_quantity%5=0) 
            then 5 else p.sum_quantity%5 end quanityofpackage
from pack_cte p
     cross apply (select ceiling(p.sum_quantity/5.0) num_packages) p_calc
     cross apply fnNumbers(1, p_calc.num_packages) fn;
```

Output

```
package sum_quantity    num_packages    subpackage  quanityofpackage
10      13              3               1           5
10      13              3               2           5
10      13              3               3           3
20      14              3               1           5
20      14              3               2           5
20      14              3               3           4
30      12              3               1           5
30      12              3               2           5
30      12              3               3           2
40      20              4               1           5
40      20              4               2           5
40      20              4               3           5
40      20              4               4           5
```